# Как запускать плагин Typit.js только по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой плагин, называется TypeIt. Я хочу сделать меню на сайте, с эффектом печатающегося текста. То есть, изначально меню нет (есть только кнопка), нажимаешь на кнопку "печатается" меню, потом я нажимаю на кнопку второй раз и меню волшебным образом исчезает. Методом проб и ошибок, я понял, что вариант со сменой класса и свойством `display: inline/none` в качества скрытия/отображения меню, не подходит: плагин просто не обновляется и при попытке вызвать меню второй раз появляется только мигающий курсор. Тогда я решил полностью удалять и добавлять меню на сайт методом `append`, а потом запускать плагин. Но ничего не работает.
Помогите связать эти два скрипта вместе.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu_btn"></button>
<div class="menu-content" id="menu-content"></div>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuBtn = $('.menu_btn');
    menuBtn.click(function(event) { 
        if (event.target.classList.contains('menu_btn_active')) {
            $(".effects").fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function () { 
                $(".effects").remove(); 
            }, );
        } else {
            $(".menu-content").append("<div class='effects' style='display: none;'>Эффект</div>"); 
            $(".effects").fadeIn();
        }
        menuBtn.toggleClass('menu_btn_active');
        return false;
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    menuBtn.click(function(event) {
        new TypeIt('.effects', {
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [документация по плагину](https://typeitjs.com/docs/) метод `reset()`

Answer (score 0):

[Документация по плагину](https://typeitjs.com/docs/) метод `reset()`

Должно получиться что-то вроде такого

```
var menuBtn = $('.menu_btn');
$(document).ready(function() {
    menuBtn.click(function(event) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('menu_init')) {
            $(".effects").fadeIn();
            new TypeIt('.effects', {
                ...........
            })
        }
        if (!$('.effects').hasClass('menu_btn_active')) {
            $('.effects')
                .fadeIn()
                .addClass('menu_btn_active')
                .reset();
        } else {
            $('.effects').removeClass('menu_btn_active').fadeOut()
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kkqm3m http://prntscr.com/kkqmi7

Comment: @PavelBogdanov Ну так нужно код самого плагина добавить перед выполнением скрипта.

Comment: @PavelBogdanov Ну да. Я просто привел пример кода, который должны написать вы. А до этого нужно добавить в разметку кнопку, меню, скрипты jquery и плагина. Я не знаю тонкостей работы данного плагина, поэтому код, приведенный в ответе условный и может потребовать корректировок.